# Нет подключения к сайту bs4

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, requests, beautiful-soup

Я написал парсер для заполнения бд джанго, вчера все работало отлично, но сегодня обнаружил, что ничего на сайт не записывается, начал проверять работу кода без записи в бд, но результат точно такой же.
Думаю, что это связанно с большим количеством попыток подключения к сайту и теперь у меня нет к нему доступа, если это так, то каким образом можно исправить положение ?

**далее сам код**

Код

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests as req
import xlrd
import pandas as pd

link = 'https://www.foxtrot.com.ua/ru/shop/led_televizory.html'
res = req.get(link)
html = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

names = []
prices = []
reviews = []
full_urls = []
category = str

for name in html.findAll("a", class_="card__title"):
    names.append(name.text)
print(names)
for price in html.findAll("div", class_="card-price"):
    prices.append(price.text.replace(' ', '').replace('\n', '').replace('₴', ''))

print(prices)

for review in html.findAll("a", class_="card__comments"):
    reviews.append(review.text)
i = -1
l =len(reviews)
while i <= l:
    i +=1
    if i == len(reviews):
        break
    else:
        if '\n\nComments\n' in reviews[i]:
            reviews[i] = '0'

i = -1
while i <= l:
    i+=1
    if i == len(reviews):
        break
    else:
        only_number = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', reviews[i])
        reviews[i] = only_number
print(reviews)

category  = html.find('h1', class_="with-counter")
print(category)

for full_url in html.findAll('a', 'card__title'):
    full_urls.append( 'https://www.foxtrot.com.ua' + full_url['href'])

i = -1

print(full_urls)
```

Результат

```
[]
[]
[]
None
[]
```

Comment: ну так распечатайте значение res.text сразу после get запроса и посмотрите что там да как. Можно даже сохранить в html файл и открыть браузером.

Comment: This request was blocked by the security rules

Comment: @KoVadim как можно это исправить

Comment: собственно Вы сами и ответили на свой вопрос. Как исправить? видимо по классике - занести админам или использовать прокси.

Comment: @KoVadim использовать прокси на самом компьютере или выпихнуть его в код программы ?

Comment: обычно в программу добавляют.